# Cannot cover up a gap between a box shadow and input field

Tags: css, input-field

Trying to create a basic website layout for a course (Odin Project). However I noticed that their website design has a perfect box shadow with no light gap. Where as my design no matter how much I try to mess with the box shadow property settings seems to have a small 1-2px gap between the box shadow and input fields. This is very noticeable and sort of ruins the design. I am a novice at CSS and was hoping someone more experienced could direct me to a good solution.

```css
.form-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
    
input {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;

  border: 1.5px solid #e5e7eb;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 9px;
}

input:focus {
  outline-color: #4a6ed6;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #bebebe;

}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2e3a4b;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  /* margin-left: 2px; */
  /* float: left; */
}
```

```html
<form action="post">
  <div class="form-row-1">
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row-2">
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row-3">
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I darkened the box shadow so you could see the gap more clearly.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I discovered what was wrong. Apparently for some reason when I used the property `outline-width` and `outline-color` it wasn't actually targeting the outline under the `input:focus` selector. I had to use the shorthand `outline: 1px solid #4a6ed6;` to get rid of the gap. So now it works.

See [**outline**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property from MDN docs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `border: none` you can set it to `1.5px solid #4a6ed6` and remove the `outline` :

```css
input {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1.5px solid #e5e7eb;
}

input:focus {
  // outline-color: #4a6ed6;
  outline: none;
  border: 1.5px solid #4a6ed6;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #bebebe;
}
```

```html
<form action="post"> 
  <div class="form-row-1">
    <div class="form-flex-container">
      <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That solves my problem as well. I'll keep this in mind as an alternative solution in the future. Thanks for the answer!